# unlimited tmpfs

Tags: linux, swap, tmpfs

How to have the advantages of tmpfs and not be limited to its small size?

I'm thinking of a shell script that runs as a daemon, monitors RAM and adds more swap files in specified folder, when memory is low, but maybe you know a better way.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what problem you're trying to solve exactly? Adding swap files dynamically sounds like a very strange thing to be wanting to do (to me).

Comment: What do you mean by “limited to its small size”? You can make the `tmpfs` as large as it needs to be, even larger than your RAM, if required.

Comment: @Marco but what will happen, when data in tmpfs exceeds total memory size?

Comment: The system will swap out the data to the disk.

Comment: @Marco I mean, when swap is full too

Comment: Then your system will seize up. Without either RAM or swap your system is unable to operate. You should prevent that from happening by limiting the size of the tmpfs. As @Mat already mentioned, since you appear to aim for something strange you should describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you want it to be indefinitely extensible, why would you use tmpfs?

Comment: A sparse zvol to back as SWAP, change size as needed?

Comment: Set the size to the entire hard drive. Worth an experiment to see if this works and gives "infinite" tmpfs.

Comment: Refer to this: http://blog.thilelli.net/post/2011/08/03/Interesting-Use-Case-Of-Solaris-Swap-Space